# Reflection with base and sub classes

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a solution with a base class and 2 sub classes, The base class has properties that applies to both sub classes and the sub classes have unique properties that only applies to that specific class.

Now, I have the following problem/question: in my base class there are some private set properties and would like to change them later on in the case of a special situation. I store my data in a generic list of type base class. Is it possible to change a value after it has been private set?

I'm trying to use reflection but can't get it to work. When debugging it strikes out because `field` is `null`.

Side note: I renamed some of the code to explain my situation better. Thank you for your time!

```
CBase test = lstClasses[0];// Assign Class instance from generic list
FieldInfo field = typeof(CBase).GetField( "City", 
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
);
field.SetValue(test, "NewCity");
```

Here is the base class :

```
 [Serializable]
public abstract class CBase
{

    //Required flieds

    public string ContactPerson { get; private set; }
    public string Cellnr { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string StreetAdress { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string Suburb { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; private set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSimple { get; private set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; private set; }

    //Optional

    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string Vatnr { get; set; }
    public string Tellnr { get; set; }
    public string PostalAdress { get; set; }
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    //Simple Constructor
    public CBase(string _CP, string _Cllnr, string _Eml, string _SrtAdrs
                , string _City, string _Subrb, string _TrnsT
                , bool _IsSimple,DateTime _DateAndTime, string _EmpC)

    {
        ContactPerson = _CP;
        Cellnr = _Cllnr;
        Email = _Eml;
        StreetAdress = _SrtAdrs;
        City = _City;
        Suburb = _Subrb;
        TransactionType = _TrnsT;
        IsSimple = _IsSimple;
        DateAndTime = _DateAndTime;
        EmployeeCode = _EmpC;

    }

    //Full Constructor
    public CBase(string _CP, string _Cllnr, string _Eml, string _SrtAdrs, string
                 _City, string _Subrb, string _TrnsT, string _Buisns
                , string _Tellnr, string _Vatnr, string _PstAd, string _AreaC
                , bool _IsSimple, DateTime _DateAndTime, string _EmpC)

    {
        ContactPerson = _CP;
        Cellnr = _Cllnr;
        Email = _Eml;
        StreetAdress = _SrtAdrs;
        City = _City;
        Suburb = _Subrb;
        DateAndTime = _DateAndTime;
        EmployeeCode = _EmpC;

        Business = _Buisns;
        Vatnr = _Vatnr;
        Tellnr = _Tellnr;
        PostalAdress = _PstAd;
        AreaCode = _AreaC;
        TransactionType = _TrnsT;

        IsSimple = _IsSimple;

    }
```

Comment: You talk about a private property, but you're attempting to work with a field. You would use `PropertyInfo` for properties, ... is `City` is your backing field or a property? Can you post the `Cbase` code?

Comment: Post class definition

Comment: Anything like that looks like you're doing something wrong and should be redesigned. As for the private set, why not create a property to set the private field?

Comment: Could you post the class definitions please, as it's hard to follow what you are trying to do and why you need reflection from your description.

Comment: I see, stupid mistake, should have been PropertyInfo not field.